# check adjacent elements java 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Let's say that i have a 4X4 2D array.
For example

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 
| 8 | 9 | 10| 11|
| 12| 13| 14| 15|
```

I need to check the adjacent elements up down and left and the adjacent alement is  not get out of bound. For example 0{1,4}, 3{2,7}, 5{1,4,6,9}.

Any help?

Thanks

Additional Inflammations.

```
grid = new boolean [][];
        for(int i=0;i<grid.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<grid.length; j++)
            grid[i][j] = false;

        }  
  grid[0][1]= true;

if(grid[i][j+1]]==true){
    //do sth
}else if(grid[i][j-1]==true){
       // do sth
    }else if(grid[i-1][j]==true){
        //    do sth
        }else if(grid[i+1][j]==true){
           //     do sth
            }
```

Comment: Ok.  What did you try so far?

Comment: some if checks like if (array2d[i,j+1]== true{do sth}), i,j-1, i-1,j, i+1,j. But i get out of bound

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add bounds checking to the front end of your if statements. For example:

```
if ((j + 1) < grid[i].length && grid[i][j + 1] == true)
```

This will ensure you do not step out of bounds by using `j + 1`. The leftmost condition is checked first and, if it is false, the whole statement is false due to the && operator.

Thus, the second condition `grid[i][j + 1] == true` will not even be evaluated and you will avoid the IndexOutOfBoundsException.